# Android - Set background for Clickable Span in a TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I am using custom class (which extends over clickable span) to link all tags in a text view and highlight them.

I use the following code to set span:

```
   SpannableString commentsContent = new SpannableString(message);
         .....Some code ....
    commentsContent.setSpan(new StringUtils.Hashtag(context),
                hashTagStart,
                hashTagEnd, 0);
```

where Hashtag Class looks this:

```
  public static class Hashtag extends ClickableSpan{
    Context context;
    TextPaint textPaint;
    public Hashtag(Context ctx) {
        super();
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

        Typeface tf = Typeface.create(("fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf"),Typeface.NORMAL);
        ds.setTextSize(30); //TODO: Text size
        ds.setColor(R.color.primary_dark);
        ds.setAntiAlias(true);
        ds.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        //Do something on click
    }
```

The output(textview in the center) is something like this:

[image: Current output]

I want the hashtag spans to be highlighted like this:

[image: Desired look]

The background color will be dynamically assigned. How can I achieve the desired effect?

**EDIT 1:**
This has to be used in a listview or recycler view. Thus, performance is also a parameter.